# Access/Substitute CreatePage outside of Gatsby-node.js

Tags: templates, gatsby, templating

I am creating a forum using Gatsby

I have develop a form that users can use to create threads to add to the forum in a page called `create.js` which which sends the data to an external DB.

Once, the user has submitted the thread, I want to create a new page using a template, normally I would use in `Gatsby-node.js`; according to the [Gatsby Docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/api-files-gatsby-node/) `Gatsby-node.js` is only run once on deployment.

Is there another way that I can access `CreatePage()` outside of `Gatsby-node.js` or is there another function I am missing?

Ultimately I want the new page to available in the Gatsby application, without redeploying, after the user has created the necessary content.

Answer (score 1):

The way Gatsby works is that all pages need to be generated at build time. You cannot add new pages without triggering a new build.

Gatsby is not a suitable platform for a forum since content changes hundreds or thousands of times a day. Gatsby is intended for content that changes infrequently such as blogs (which might update a few times a day).

Answer (score 0):

I order to generate pages without using `CreatePage` in `Gatsby-node.js`, Gatsby advises to use `@reach/Router` and `matchPage` to extend the client application's router, we call this functionality (Client-only Routes)

more info [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/)